# What does this folder icon with two blue arrows mean?

Tags: windows, icons

While browzing through my Windows directory, I found the Panther subdirectory, which had this icon:

[image: Odd Windows directory icon]

Does anyone know what this signifies? I was able to open it normally, and it was, to all appearances, a normal directory.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- This means the folder is compressed. You can right click on a folder
  and see that **Compress contents to save disk space** is checked.

[image: Compressed Folders]

- The Panther folder is created when you first install Windows or when you
  run the Media Creation Tool or Update Assistance Tool from Microsoft.

[image]

- The NTFS file system used by Windows has a built-in compression feature known as NTFS compression. NTFS compression makes files smaller on your hard drive. NTFS compression is ideal for files you rarely access and saving space on small HDD.
- To get started, right-click the file, folder, or drive you want to compress/decompress and select Properties. Click the Advanced button under Attributes. Enable/Disable the Compress contents to save disk space check box and click OK twice. If you enabled compression for a folder, Windows will ask you whether you also want to encrypt sub folders and files.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was the new Compression display. (It used to be the folder name was in blue instead of black).