# Win 10 Home v 1803 - Remove blue arrows on compressed file/folder icons?

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, compression, windows-10-v1803

Anyone know how to remove the blue arrows displayed on compressed file/folder icons in Win 10 v 1803?

Apparently there was a simple registry tweak to remove them in older versions of Windows 10, but doesn't work newer versions.

Comment: Just to clarify - i mean the double blue arrows in upper right corner of icons on compressed files/folder, not the blue arrow on shortcut icons.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a screenshot? It almost sounds like you are talking about the OneDrive sync symbol

Answer (score 1):

On a current Windows version, the following works:

- add an empty.ico icon file to System32 folder
- add the following changes to your registry

Changes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"179"="empty.ico,0"
```

- in task manager, right-click Explorer then Restart
- the overlay is gone

(from https://nerdshack.co.uk/windows-10-an%E2%80%8Bd-double-arrow-icon-of-)death/

---

Instead if your icon is related to OneDrive, you will want to disable it with ShellExView:

(see Description columns for other possible entries you may have)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aybe, will try - I don't have that reg key ('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons')  but will add w new string value, and see what happens. I read somewhere that that particular fix worked in the original Win 10 but not later versions ... fingers crossed.                                                                                     In reply to @LPChip, sorry for not being clearer - it's like the one in this post - [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1209072/what-does-this-folder-icon-with-two-blue-arrows-mean)

Comment: I've tried in the latest big Windows update : RS4/1803 and indeed it works

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Win 10 Pro N 1804

Create blank .ico with Icon tool (I used [IcoFX Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/icofx_portable))
with all sizes (16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 256x256) filled with a transparent image (default new image in IcoFX), save under **C:/ as blank.ico** and run this reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons]
"179"="C:/blank.ico,0"
```

Somehow it saves as "black" icon under C:/Windows/, which was a way previous fixes used.